# Matlab to Python conversion - testing the Lanczos algorithm

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to convert a Matlab code to a Python one. I have a working Lanczos algorithm in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from math import factorial
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

def Lanczos(A,m):
  [n,k] = size(A)
  V =  zeros[k, m+1]
  V[:,2]= rand[k,1]
  V[:,2]=V[:,2]/norm[V[:,2],2]
  beta[2]=0
  for j in range [2: m+2]:
      w=A*V[:,j] - beta[j]*V[:,j-1]
      alpha[j]=w.transpose()*V[:,j]
      w = w - alpha[j]*V[:,j]
      beta[j+1]=norm[w,2]
      V[:,j+1]= w/beta[j+1]
      T=sparse[m+1,m+1]
      disp("approximation quality is: ", (norm(V*T*V.transpose()-A)))
      for i in range [2: m+1]:
          T[i-1,i-1]=alpha[i]
          T[i-1,i]=beta[i+1]
          T[i,i-1]=beta[i+1]
          T[m+1, m+1]=alpha[m+2]
          V=V[:,2:end-1]
          disp("approximating eigenvalues are: ",(eigs(T).transpose()))
```

but when I am trying to 'test' the diagonalisation with the following matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from math import factorial
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

def Lanczos(A,m):
  [n,k] = size(A)
  V =  zeros[k, m+1]
  V[:,2]= rand[k,1]
  V[:,2]=V[:,2]/norm[V[:,2],2]
  beta[2]=0
  for j in range [2: m+2]:
      w=A*V[:,j] - beta[j]*V[:,j-1]
      alpha[j]=w.transpose()*V[:,j]
      w = w - alpha[j]*V[:,j]
      beta[j+1]=norm[w,2]
      V[:,j+1]= w/beta[j+1]
      T=sparse[m+1,m+1]
      disp("approximation quality is: ", (norm(V*T*V.transpose()-A)))
      for i in range [2: m+1]:
          T[i-1,i-1]=alpha[i]
          T[i-1,i]=beta[i+1]
          T[i,i-1]=beta[i+1]
          T[m+1, m+1]=alpha[m+2]
          V=V[:,2:end-1]
          disp("approximating eigenvalues are: ",(eigs(T).transpose()))
  def test (A,m,i):
      A=rand(5,12)
      A=A.dot(A.transpose()

      for i in range [2:4]:
          disp("runnung for" , str(i), "rounds")
          Lanczos(A,i)
          disp("eigenvalues are", (flipud(eig(A))))
```

I keep getting an 'invalid syntax' after the last loop. I think I just can apply the algorithm to the matrix correctly, but I simply can't get my head around it. 
Thanks for the help!

A picture of the error message:
[image]

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Asterisk imports are discouraged. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: That's the error message, there is nothing more to it. I will change the names and see if it's better.

Comment: Error messages usually include far more information than that, like a full traceback.

Comment: I edited my original post with a screenshot from the error message itself. I don't get anything more and that confuses me.

Comment: Didn't use python for some years, but isn't range a function which is called with ()?

Comment: Usually yes, but lists are defined with squared brackets in Python and I thought I can define a range function with a list. I can't find an example of that online, so it seems I am not correct. I changed the code to 'for in in range(3)', but I get the same error.

Comment: the following might help you https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23536/quality-of-eigenvalue-approximation-in-lanczos-method .

Comment: Thank you, it does help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to find out the problem- it was a missing bracket:

```
def test (A,m,i):
    A=rand(5,12)
    A=A.dot(A.transpose())
    disp("eigenvalues are", (flipud(LA.eig(A))))
    Lanczos(A,i)
```

after A.transpose I needed a second bracket....

I re-wrote the script and now it looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from math import factorial
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import linalg as LA

def Lanczos(A,m, k, beta_1, j=20):
    V = np.zeros([k, m+1])
    V[:,2]= rand(k,1)
    beta_1=(j)
    alpha=(j)
    for j  in range (m+2):
        w=A*V[:,j] - beta_1*V[:,j-1]
        alpha=w.transpose()*V[:,j]
        w = w - alpha*V[:,j]
        beta[j+1]=norm[w,2]
        V[:,j+1]= w/beta[j+1]
        T=sparse[m+1,m+1]
        print("approximation quality is: ", (norm(V*T*V.transpose()-A)))
        for i in range [2: m+1]:
            T[i-1,i-1]=alpha[i]
            T[i-1,i]=beta[i+1]
            T[i,i-1]=beta[i+1]
            T[m+1, m+1]=alpha[m+2]
            V=V[:,2:end-1]
            print("approximating eigenvalues are: ",(eigs(T).transpose()))
            return 

Lanczos (A=rand(5,12), m = 4, k=1, beta_1=1)
```

now I get the error message:
'    w = w - alpha*V[:,j]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,12) (12,5) ' but I will have to debug it more to make everything work. Thanks for the help!